# React - Render Objects with changing Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, react-state

Simply put, I would like to build an interface with which a user can insert objects into a div.

The user should be able to select placed objects and change their settings (color, size, rotation ..).

I am brand new to react and have put my ideas into practice.

```
class Elements extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.displayData = [];

    this.state = {
        showdata: this.displayData,
        elementData: {
            color: "red",
        }
    };
    this.addDiv = this.addDiv.bind(this);
    this.switchColor = this.switchColor.bind(this);
    this.giveConsoleData = this.giveConsoleData.bind(this);
};

giveConsoleData(){
    console.log(this.state);
}
switchColor() {
    if(this.state.elementData.color == "red"){
        this.setState({
            showdata: this.displayData,
            elementData: {
                color: "blue",

            }
        });
    }else if(this.state.elementData.color == "blue"){
        this.setState({
            showdata: this.displayData,
            elementData: {
                color: "red",

            }
        });
    }
}
addDiv() {
    this.displayData.push(<div style={this.state.elementData} ><FaArrowUp size={32} /></div>);
    this.setState({
        showdata : this.displayData
    });
}
render() {
    const items = this.state.showdata.map(i => <li>{i}</li>);
    return (
        <div>
            <Button type="submit" block variant="primary" onClick={this.addDiv}>Primary</Button>< br/>
            <Button type="submit" block variant="primary" onClick={this.switchColor}>ChangeColor</Button>< br/>
            <Button type="submit" block variant="primary" onClick={this.giveConsoleData}>Consolenlog</Button>< br/>


            {items}

            <div style={this.state.elementData}><h1>I Can Change</h1></div>

        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Elements;
```

My problem now is that the `h1` heading can change color, but objects that have already been placed cannot.

Do I have the completely wrong approach?

Is it maybe that when you push the div element the current color value is saved and not the color element from the state?

Comment: Hi @christopherGhl , can you provide live working fiddle example with some dummy data.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ChristopherG/pen/vYOeLvE

Comment: It think you are right in your suspicion. I would pass `this.state.elementData` to your component in `render()` not in `addDiv()`

Comment: I would also not recommend storing React components in an array. I would store data in the array, and then in your render function, decide what to render based on the data.
 
With your current example, the only thing your `displayData` needs to keep track of is how many items to render. Then in `render` you can simply render that many `<div style={this.state.elementData} ><FaArrowUp size={32} /></div>`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling my comments into an answer with some code:

It think you are right in your suspicion. I would pass `this.state.elementData` to your component in `render()` not in `addDiv()`.

I would also not recommend storing React components in an array. I would store data in the array, and then in your render function, decide what to render based on the data. With your current example, the only thing your `displayData` needs to keep track of is how many items to render. Then in render you can simply render that many `<div style={this.state.elementData} ><FaArrowUp size={32} /></div>`s.

Here's how I would change up your code (albeit a little rushed) to attempt what you are describing:

Updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/zekehernandez/pen/RwPLavZ

```
class Elements extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        showdata: [],
        elementData: {
            color: "red",
        }
    };
    this.addDiv = this.addDiv.bind(this);
    this.switchColor = this.switchColor.bind(this);
    this.giveConsoleData = this.giveConsoleData.bind(this);
};

giveConsoleData(){
    console.log(this.state);
}
switchColor() {
    if(this.state.elementData.color == "red"){
        this.setState({
            elementData: {
                color: "blue",

            }
        });
    }else if(this.state.elementData.color == "blue"){
        this.setState({
            elementData: {
                color: "red",

            }
        });
    }
}
addDiv() {
  this.setState((state, props) => {
    showdata : state.showdata.push(state.showdata.length)
  });
}
render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <button type="submit" block variant="primary" onClick={this.addDiv}>Add Object</button>< br/>
            <button type="submit" block variant="primary" onClick={this.switchColor}>ChangeColor</button>< br/>
            <button type="submit" block variant="primary" onClick={this.giveConsoleData}>Consolenlog</button>< br/>


            {this.state.showdata.map(itemIndex => (
              <div style={this.state.elementData} >item: {itemIndex}</div>
            ))} 

            <div><h1 style={this.state.elementData}>I Can Change</h1></div>

        </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Elements />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: This helped me, thank you. Is is possible to save different objects and different settings for each of them in the state? Something like: Objectlist:{Object1{Setting 1x,Setting 2x}}Object2{Setting 1y, Setting 2z}}

Comment: Absolutely, your state can be anything (an array, and object, whatever) and your React code can choose to render whatever based on what your state is. I'm using "whatever" here because really there's a lot of flexibility. You said you are brand new to React, so I would suggest reading through the React docs, especially this one: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html 
Most of the Main Concepts are fairly straightforward, but that one is the turning point in my opinion.